# How to automatically append the firebase script tag for flutter web using Github Actions or another resource?

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart

I currently have a release pipeline that goes something like this:

`Push to Github Repo -> Github Actions runs flutter build web -> Website released on my Github Pages`.

I want to implement Firebase with my app, however it requires there to be an additional script tag (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/) in the index.html file, which is generated by `flutter build web`. Therefore every time I push an update, I have to go into the branch and edit the index.html with the additional script.

I was wondering if there was a way that I could either edit my project setup so the script tag stays in the index.html file on build, or if there was a way to change my Github Actions so the script is automatically appended to the generated file.

Thanks.